# How can I remove Ubuntu and stay with Manjaro?

Tags: dual-boot

I am beginner to Linux

Trying to learn Linux.

I have latest Manjaro 20. I have installed Ubuntu for some reason. Now I want to remove Ubuntu and stay with only Manjaro.

1. How do I completely remove Ubuntu and retrieve the space I gave it ?
2. How do I remove grub menu?

Ubuntu is stored in `/dev/sda5`

I want remove `/dev/sda5`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrtfK.jpg

Comment: You have the old BIOS/MBR configuration. You need first to make sure grub is booting your Manjaro install. Or correct grub is in MBR.

Comment: Boot a *live* system and delete the partition. If however Ubuntu owns your MBR, your system will no longer boot (as the pointer for booting the system will point to a no-longer-existing partition resulting in grub rescue appearing), so ensure Manjaro owns the MBR. This issue can also be solved in Manjaro, but this is a Ubuntu support site, so Manjaro is off-topic as I read the site rules. *Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic*